# Jquery-TypeError: jQuery(...).MyFunc is not a function

Tags: jquery

i tried searching the same problem and applied the solution but getting the same error. in my HTML i have this

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function ($) {
    $.fn.MyFunc = function (options) {
        alert("hi!");
    }
})(jQuery);

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery().MyFunc();
});
</script>
```

I'm newbie in JQuery,

Thanks in advance

Comment: Works great for me.. Check if `jquery` is loaded properly or not..

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. Can you help me how can i check if the jquery is loaded properly?. Thanks :)

Comment: *After writing your jquery code* .. if jquery not included you should get an error with `$ is not defined` or `jQuery is not defined`

Comment: check the page source and right click jquery script tag and do Open in new tab/window, if jquery loads proper it will show you js source code or 404 not found page

Comment: Thanks guys for the reply i have a conflict on my ilbrary. its working fine now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
(function ($) {
        $.fn.MyFunc = function (options) {
            alert("hi!");
        }
    })(jQuery);

    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery().MyFunc();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

its working fine

did you try to call

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1 /jquery.min.js"></script>
```

instead of this

`<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: please check there should be call jquery.min.js only one time, also check your console the error will be mentioned there and send me a screenshot of your console log.

Comment: thanks Raj i figured it already i have a conflict on my library :)

Comment: it's OK, enjoy your programming  :)